# Advanced mysql query which sort down specific records on result set irrespective of its default sorting?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sorting

I have a query which actually have a sorting using order by clause. i have a table like following...

```
user_id   user_name   user_age   user_state   user_points 
1         Rakul       30         CA           56
2         Naydee      29         NY           144
3         Jeet        40         NJ           43
.....
```

i have following query...

```
select * from users where user_state = 'NY' order by user_points desc limit 50;
```

This gives me the list of 50 people with most points. I wanted to give least preference to few people who's id's were known. Incase if i do not have enough 50 records then those id's should come in the last in the list. I do not want the users 2 and 3 to come on top of the list even though they have higher points... those people should come on the last of the list from the query. Is there any way to push specific records to last on result set irrespective of query sorting ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move specific records (like user_id = 2 and 3) down to the list; Then you can run below Query:

```
mysql> select *,IF(user_id=2 or user_id=3,0,1) as list_order from users where user_state = 'NY' order by list_order desc, user_points desc limit 50;
```

Comment: thank you for your reply... but i want that id's too sorted based on user_points... i mean if the ids 2,3,0,1 are having points as 40,80,20,30 then in the resultset these ids has to come last and also in the order 3,2,1,0 which stands for 80,40,30,20 points...

Comment: Those ids will be sorted as well with the given query. Check the demo here: <http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d4a1/2>

Comment: sorry... just checked with it... i actually need the specific ids in the same order that i mention... that ids has to come on the last of result set but in the order i mention... i mean ... if i say... user_id = 2 or user_id=1 then in the resultset this should reflect same... the userid_2 has to come before user_id 1 irrespective of the user_points. sorry for the confusion in my first comment... thanks a lot for your help...

Comment: In that case you should be using something like:     mysql> SELECT *,CASE WHEN user_id=2 THEN '0' WHEN user_id=1 THEN '1' ELSE '2' END as list_order from users where user_state = 'NY' order by list_order asc, user_points desc limit 50;

Comment: nope... i get syntax error on this... select *,IF(user_id=2 or user_id=3,0,1) as list_order

Comment: I have missed the bracket while writing the query manually here.. well, here's the tested and verified version.    
       mysql> SELECT *, (CASE WHEN id=5 THEN '1' WHEN id=8 THEN '2' 
           WHEN id=6 THEN '3' 
           ELSE '0' END) as list_order from users where user_state='NY' order by list_order asc, user_points desc limit 50;
You can also check the o/p here - [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88d60/6]

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
    select *
    from users
    where user_state = 'NY'
    -- this order by ensures that 2 and 3 are included
    order by case when user_id in (2,3) then 1 else 2 end, user_points desc
    limit 50
) as top48plus2n3
-- this order by ensures that 2 and 3 are last
order by case when user_id in (2,3) then 2 else 1 end, user_points desc
```

**Edit**: changed `id` by `user_id` and corrected outside `order by` (sorry about that)

On the inner select:
By using this `case` calculation, what you do is ensuring that records with ids equal to 2 and 3 are "important" (firstly ordered in the order by). Those receive 1 while the others receive 2 as order value, only after that points are relevant.

On the outer select:
Records with ids 2 and 3 recieve 2 as order value, while the rest recieve 1. So they go last irrespective of its "default"

Here you have a reduced fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/377c1/1

Comment: thank you for helping me... but it did not worked for me. can u tell me what case... else... do in order by ?

Comment: I hope I did understud now.

Comment: thank you sir. but the solution did not worked for me... i query stuffs separately and merged in php to finish the task... thank you for helping me.